# Tell me please. I have an error output about an incorrect password above the login/password fields. How can I display it on the main page?

Tags: php

please tell me how to implement the output of a message about a wrong password to the main page? now I have a message appearing above the login/password fields.

```
 <?php
session_start();
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/engine/data/main_config.php');
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/engine/core/mysql_connect.php');
if($_POST['response']) {
  $captcha = $_POST['response'];
  $secret = "6LfZjeIbAAAAALhKqTKfXlB14lAbj";
  $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=". $secret . "&response=" . $captcha), true);
  if(!$json['success']) {
    echo '<center></center>';
    include('algo.php');
    die();
}
}  else {
   echo '<center><div class="form-block-error"><b>Хмм. Докажите что вы не бот :)</b></div></center>';
   include('algo.php');
   die();
}
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM dle_users WHERE name LIKE '".$_POST['login']."'");
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
$password_mysql = $mysqli->query("select password from dle_users where name='".$_POST['login']."'")->fetch_object()->password;
$realname = $mysqli->query("select name from dle_users where name='".$_POST['login']."'")->fetch_object()->name;
if (!password_verify(urldecode($_POST['password']), $password_mysql)) {
    echo '<center><div class="form-block-error"><b>You entered the wrong password, try again or restore the password</b></div></center><script>grecaptcha.reset();</script>';
} else {
    $_SESSION['login'] = $realname;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
}
   } else {
echo '<center><div class="form-block-error"><b></b></div></center><script>grecaptcha.reset();</script>';
}
   include('algo.php');

?>
```

Comment: You're going to need to include A LOT more information if you want anyone to be able to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I can't put all the code here, it gives an error, what should I do?

Comment: You should read page I sent. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I sent the code, thank you

Comment: Instead of echoing the error message directly, save it in a variable and output it where you need on the page.

Comment: Tell me how you can implement saving a variable, please